# GridView not display Images

Tags: android

i want to create a products gallery in my application , so i create Gallery

Activity and insert a Grid View in Gallery layout

and using Base adapter to display data,but when i run application blank activity displayed

Custom adapter code:

```
public class GalleryManager extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<Drawable> list;
    int[] id;

    public GalleryManager(Context context , int[] id ) {
        this.context = context;
        //this.list = list;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(id[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

using in gallery activity :

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.galleryGridView);
        int id[] = {
                R.drawable.gallery1,
                R.drawable.gallery2,
                R.drawable.gallery3
        };
        gridView.setAdapter(new GalleryManager(this,id));
```

View in layout:

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/galleryGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Array Length to your `getCount()` method,change your getCount method

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return id.length;
    }
```

I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This case happens because you don't properly return your array size and array item in your custom adapter.

Update your getCount method to return number of drawables:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.getSize();
}
```

And update your getItem method to return your DrawableItem:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public GalleryManager(Context context , int[] id ,List<Drawable> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.id = id;
    }
```

**update your getCount method like this:**

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

and **update your getItem method like this:**

```
 @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }
```